# MVC ELMAH and SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, elmah, elmah.mvc

back-story:
We mainly use AWS for everything (hosting, database, notifications, etc.). Now, I'm looking at moving the database side to SQL Azure since we've been getting crazy bills on AWS RDS. So all I tried to do was create a DB in SQL Azure and update the connection string to point to the new DB. In the past, ELMAH (this specific implementation: https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc) worked flawlessly in the past.

current situation:
I just created a new DB in SQL Azure and noticed key differences right away namely on not supporting:

ON [PRIMARY], NONCLUSTERED KEYS, etc.

I migrated my db fine (for now), but when I applied the updated scripts for ELMAH to the db and tried to go into the tool, I get errors!

**I'm somehow convinced that it's a db problem**, because if I remove: 
`<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>`  which basically defaults ELMAH to store everything locally, I get to access ELMAH.

Anybody got ELMAH to work on SQL Azure? Could you give me the SQL script to generate the tables and stored procedures?

Comment: What does the DefaultConnection string look like (obfuscate user/pwd/dbname)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is the db script I use for ELMAH DBs on SQl Azure:

```
--~Changing index [dbo].[ELMAH_Error].PK_ELMAH_Error to a clustered index.  You may    want to pick a different index to cluster on.
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].    [ELMAH_Error]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error](
[ErrorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Application] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
[Host] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Source] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
[Message] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[User] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[StatusCode] [int] NOT NULL,
[TimeUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Sequence] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AllXml] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ELMAH_Error] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ErrorId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ELMAH_Error]') AND name = N'IX_ELMAH_Error_App_Time_Seq')
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ELMAH_Error_App_Time_Seq] ON [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] 
(
[Application] ASC,
[TimeUtc] DESC,
[Sequence] DESC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE  = OFF)
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id =     OBJECT_ID(N'[DF_ELMAH_Error_ErrorId]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ELMAH_Error] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ELMAH_Error_ErrorId]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ErrorId]
END

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorsXml]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorsXml]
(
@Application NVARCHAR(60),
@PageIndex INT = 0,
@PageSize INT = 15,
@TotalCount INT OUTPUT
)
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @FirstTimeUTC DATETIME
DECLARE @FirstSequence INT
DECLARE @StartRow INT
DECLARE @StartRowIndex INT

SELECT 
    @TotalCount = COUNT(1) 
FROM 
    [ELMAH_Error]
WHERE 
    [Application] = @Application

-- Get the ID of the first error for the requested page

SET @StartRowIndex = @PageIndex * @PageSize + 1

IF @StartRowIndex <= @TotalCount
BEGIN

    SET ROWCOUNT @StartRowIndex

    SELECT  
        @FirstTimeUTC = [TimeUtc],
        @FirstSequence = [Sequence]
    FROM 
        [ELMAH_Error]
    WHERE   
        [Application] = @Application
    ORDER BY 
        [TimeUtc] DESC, 
        [Sequence] DESC

END
ELSE
BEGIN

    SET @PageSize = 0

END

-- Now set the row count to the requested page size and get
-- all records below it for the pertaining application.

SET ROWCOUNT @PageSize

SELECT 
    errorId     = [ErrorId], 
    application = [Application],
    host        = [Host], 
    type        = [Type],
    source      = [Source],
    message     = [Message],
    [user]      = [User],
    statusCode  = [StatusCode], 
    time        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), [TimeUtc], 126) + ''Z''
FROM 
    [ELMAH_Error] error
WHERE
    [Application] = @Application
AND
    [TimeUtc] <= @FirstTimeUTC
AND 
    [Sequence] <= @FirstSequence
ORDER BY
    [TimeUtc] DESC, 
    [Sequence] DESC
FOR
    XML AUTO

' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorXml]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_GetErrorXml]
(
@Application NVARCHAR(60),
@ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    [AllXml]
FROM 
    [ELMAH_Error]
WHERE
    [ErrorId] = @ErrorId
AND
    [Application] = @Application

' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].    [ELMAH_LogError]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ELMAH_LogError]
(
@ErrorId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@Application NVARCHAR(60),
@Host NVARCHAR(30),
@Type NVARCHAR(100),
@Source NVARCHAR(60),
@Message NVARCHAR(500),
@User NVARCHAR(50),
@AllXml NVARCHAR(MAX),
@StatusCode INT,
@TimeUtc DATETIME
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT
INTO
    [ELMAH_Error]
    (
        [ErrorId],
        [Application],
        [Host],
        [Type],
        [Source],
        [Message],
        [User],
        [AllXml],
        [StatusCode],
        [TimeUtc]
    )
VALUES
    (
        @ErrorId,
        @Application,
        @Host,
        @Type,
        @Source,
        @Message,
        @User,
        @AllXml,
        @StatusCode,
        @TimeUtc
    )

' 
END
GO
```

SQL Azure is a special version of SQL and there are some things that it wont support.

Did you use the SQL Azure Migrate Wizard to migrate your db?

Comment: Yes I tried using the tool. On your SQL script, I had the same one but tried anyway and it stil doesn't work. :(
I'm really sure it's with the db because if I remove the connectionString for ELMAH (meaning it stores logs locally), I get into the interface.
Do you have ELMAH on a seperate DB with a seperate connection string? I used to have a seperate DB but now I just use the defaultconnection.

Comment: Have you tried a vanilla version of ELMAH?? This could be Implementation specific.

Comment: I was having problems using elmah on Azure your SQL Script fixed it for me.

Comment: Your script fixed the problem where others failed.  Maybe we can get Atif to include your script in the repo :-)

Comment: For those who use EF Migrations, here is the [migration.cs for SQLServer and AzureSQL](https://gist.github.com/danmusk/7265235)

Comment: Works in my Azure web app - Spring 2017. Thanks